# Android web view with notification

Tags: android

I want to implement payments into my application. Now i came to conclusion that i will call one URL in the web view. This url will be on my server and user will interact with the webpage. Now when user click submit after providing the details then my server will interact with the payment gateway and makes the payment.

Now here i m stucked. How can i get the information that user payment is successfully done.? and i can show an alert message to user.

is there any web view inbuilt method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {     @Override     public void   onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {   
//Here put launch a service or to show the notification to the user.
```

} 
});

This is a way. It may not be reliable becuase the fact that if the payment isnt successful then it will still alert the user.

But this is possibly a way.